# In Access VBA, calculate a total from an array for a variable group

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an array that I've created from a dynamic query. For each item and date in a range, I get several values. That's all good. But I need to be able to calculate a total for each group (not each row) and use that total as the beginning value for the following date range for 29 weeks.

In VBA, I have an ending total for each row of data. I can then use that total in the following date range.

The problem with my code is the ending total is for each row, not each group.

Using a query (which I'm using as the data source for a report), I can get the correct ending total using an expression.

The problem with the query is the beginning value is not available.

```
    If cRequired < Week1 Then

    recOut.AddNew
    recOut.Fields("ItemNumber") = cItem
    recOut.Fields("tB") = cOnHand
    recOut.Fields("tPO") = cPO
    recOut.Fields("tBC") = cBC
    recOut.Fields("tSO") = CSO
    recOut.Fields("tPD") = cPD
    recOut.Fields("tIN") = cIN
    recOut.Fields("tJT") = cJT
    recOut.Fields("tWO") = cWO
    recOut.Fields("tE") = cOnHand + cPO + cBC + CSO + cPD + cIN + cJT + cWO
    recOut.Fields("RequiredDate") = cRequired
    recOut.Fields("GroupDate") = Week1
    recOut.Update

    tEPast = cOnHand + cPO + cBC + CSO + cPD + cIN + cJT + cWO

   End If
```

The following data is available via the query. The Ending Total is a calculated expression in the query and is correct. The Beginning value is written to the table by the code. It's not correct.

```
[tB]+[SumOftPO]+[SumOftBC]+[SumOftSO]+[SumOftPD]+[SumOftIN]+[SumOftJT]+[SumOftWO]

009 1623.39 0   -106.404    0   0   0   0   0   2/19/2017   1516.87
009 1572.39 0   -390.477    0   0   0   0   0   2/26/2017   1182.14
009 1522.39 0   -414.684    0   0   0   0   0   3/5/2017    1107.07
```

For the first row, the code gets the value for `cOnHand` 4 times since there are 4 raw dates (below). The calculation for `tE` runs against the same value `cOnHand` 4 times, one per row. So, the beginning value for the next bucket is wrong.

```
009  1623.39    0   -9.724  0   0   0   0   0   1613.667    2/12/2017
009  1623.39    0   -44.88  0   0   0   0   0   1578.511    2/13/2017
009  1623.39    0   -1.4    0   0   0   0   0   1621.991    2/15/2017
009  1623.39    0   -50.4   0   0   0   0   0   1572.991    2/17/2017
```

Not quite sure what approach to take or how to get the correct totals, either via the code (correct ending total) or via a query (correct beginning value).

What I'd like to see ...

```
009 1623.91 0   -106.40     0   0   0   0   0   2/19/2017   1516.87
009 1516.87 0   -390.47     0   0   0   0   0   2/26/2017   1126.39
009 1126.39 0   -414.68     0   0   0   0   0   3/5/2017     711.71
```

Comment: I dont think there is enough information provided for anyone to be able to pinpoint your issue. I have the distinct feeling that some of your variables arent getting set.

Comment: Thanks Doug. Appreciate that you took a close look. The variables are being set. The data sets I posted are from the working table update. I have a solution. Not the best, but working. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a working solution for this. Since I had the correct value calculated in the query, I read it back into a variable and used that to set the next beginning value. Used the following DLookup instead of trying to handle the calculation directly.

Instead of :

```
 tEPast = cOnHand + cPO + cBC + CSO + cPD + cIN + cJT + cWO
```

Changed to :

```
Dim tryme As Double
        tryme = DLookup("teMe", "qBuckets", "GroupDate = Week1")
        tE0 = tryme
```